# sssd or ldap.conf doesn't work without a bindDN and password in RHEL 5, but works in RHEL 6 and 7. Why?

Tags: rhel, ldap, openldap, sssd

I am trying to use LDAP for authentication. 
I see it doesn't work with RHEL 5, if we don't provide a bind DN and password, but works in RHEL 6 and 7.

From sssd logs, I can understand that it is using the username for which it is trying to authenticate as bind DN in RHEL 6 and 7, but not in RHEL 5.

**Eg:**

> user = sam, base= ou=People,ou=HR,o=MyOrg

In RHEL 6&7, it succeeds by doing the following bind:

> Executing simple bind as: uid=sam,ou=People,ou=HR,o=MyOrg

In RHEL 5, it is just:

> Executing simple bind as: (null)

Openquery is not allowed at the server end. Hence, it fails in RHEL 5. (Server is not managed by us)

It seems to be a feature added in sssd in RHEL 6 and 7, but is it possible to achieve the same in RHEL 5?

I've also tried to achieve with ldap.conf in RHEL 6 and 7, but I couldn't figure out how to provide password. So, I guess it's a feature comes with SSSD.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't allow unauthenticated domain enumeration (you probably don't), you may want to consider the possibility that your RHEL 6 and 7 servers are actually using a Kerberos machine account to authenticate against the domain and perform an authenticated LDAP search, as this is the standard mechanism used by SSSD to maintain an authenticated connection to a given domain.